# Разница между "могло быть" и "могло бы быть"

Tags: семантика

Подскажите смысловую разницу между "могло быть" и "могло бы быть".

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Смысловой разницы тут и правда почти нет, если не заниматься совсем уж формальными поисками. И то, и другое в общем-то означает событие, которое не реализовалось, или в отношении которого точно не известно, реализовалось ли оно. Замените "быть" на любой другой глагол - и все станет понятно.
*Это могло совершиться - это могло бы совершиться.*
Все контекста разница не улавливается. 
Более того, конструкция "могло было бы быть" (в принципе тоже допускаемая грамматикой) тоже ничем по смыслу не отличается от первых двух. 
В контексте, правда, разницу можно почувствовать.

*Решение могло быть принято год назад.*
Здесь скорее всего утверждается, что решение принято, и было это, вероятно, год назад.

*Решение могло бы быть принято год назад.* 
Здесь надо понимать, что решение (скорее всего) либо не принято, либо не год назад - и автор хочет об этом поговорить или дать оценку.

Хотя в обоих случаях все это лишь одна из возможных трактовок.

При этом у оборотов есть некоторая разница грамматическая. "Могло бы быть" используется для условного наклонения в настоящем времени, там, где просто "могло быть" возможно только для прошедшего времени.

*Это могло быть, получи он письмо вовремя.* 
Событие могло быть в прошлом.

*Это могло бы быть, получи он письмо вовремя.*
Событие могло быть в прошлом или настоящем.

Хотя и тут можно и по-другому трактовать.

Comment: По всей видимости, "могло бы быть" может относиться не только к прошлому и настоящему, но и к будущему - например, после условного оборота. Если бы орудие убийства нашли, на завтрашнем процессе это могло бы быть решающим аргументом стороны обвинения.

Comment: Ну да, наверное. Я умышленно исключил из рассмотрение будущее время, поскольку грамматически оно аналогично настоящему, а вот семантика не всегда прозрачна. Да и контекстно событие условного будущего - вещь в себе. Лучше не влезать, не имея желанием провести время в бесконечных схоластических спорах.

Comment: Но ваш пример неудачен. Условие "если бы нашли" не обязвтельно означает здесь "найти в будущем". Надо именно нереальное условие. *"Если бы завтра я стала владычицей морскою, я бы не осталась у разбитого корыта"*. - и то без "завтра" не совсем ясно получается.

Answer (score 4):

Наклонение глаголов действительно разное: изъявительное и условное,отсюда и  смысловая разница. Могло быть - утверждение, могло бы быть - допущение при определённых условиях, предположение.